# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Post method is not working for one to many mapping in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I use the technologies jpa, hibernate, spring boot - data, api REST, MySql
Please help me out regarding this ERROR..!

```
Hibernate: select creditcard0_.credit_id as credit_i1_2_0_, creditcard0_.cardno as cardno2_2_0_, creditcard0_.creditname as creditna3_2_0_, creditcard0_.cvv as cvv4_2_0_, creditcard0_.uid as uid5_2_0_ from credit_card creditcard0_ where creditcard0_.credit_id=? Hibernate: insert into credit_card (cardno, creditname, cvv, uid, credit_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2022-12-22 11:39:10.208  WARN 2368 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000 2022-12-22 11:39:10.208 ERROR 2368 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'uid' cannot be null 2022-12-22 11:39:10.209  INFO 2368 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements 2022-12-22 11:39:10.223 ERROR 2368 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'uid' cannot be null at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
```

```
Here is my code:

**User.java**
```

```
import java.io.Serializable; import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Access; import javax.persistence.AccessType; import javax.persistence.CascadeType; import javax.persistence.Column; import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.FetchType; import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id; import javax.persistence.JoinColumn; import javax.persistence.ManyToOne; import javax.persistence.OneToMany; import javax.persistence.OneToOne; import javax.persistence.Table; import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator; import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;

@Transactional @Entity @Table(name="users") public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
@Column(name="phoneno")
private int phone_no;
@Column(name="address")
private String address;
private String pwd;




@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<CreditCard> creditcard;




public User() {
    
    }



public User(String name, String email, int phone_no, String address, String pwd) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
    this.address = address;
    this.pwd=pwd;
}
public Set<CreditCard> getCreditcard() {
    return creditcard;
}

public void setCreditcard(Set<CreditCard> creditcard) {
    this.creditcard = creditcard;
}




public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail_id(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public int getPhone_no() {
    return phone_no;
}
public void setPhone_no(int phone_no) {
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getPwd() {
    return pwd;
}
public void setPwd(String pwd) {
    this.pwd = pwd;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [uid=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", phone_no=" + phone_no
            + ", address=" + address + ", pwd=" + pwd + "]";
}
}
```

```
**CreditCard.java**
```

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Transactional
@Entity
@Table(name="credit_card")
public class CreditCard implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    private int credit_id;
    private String cardno;
    private String cvv;
    private String creditname;
    
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="uid",nullable = true)
    private User user;
    
    public CreditCard() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public CreditCard( String cardno, String cvv, String creditname,User user) {
        super();
        //this.credit_id = credit_id;
        this.cardno = cardno;
        this.cvv = cvv;
        this.creditname = creditname;
        this.user=user;
    }
    public int getCredit_id() {
        return credit_id;
    }
    public void setCredit_id(int credit_id) {
        this.credit_id = credit_id;
    }
    public String getCardno() {
        return cardno;
    }
    public void setCardno(String cardno) {
        this.cardno = cardno;
    }
    public String getCvv() {
        return cvv;
    }
    public void setCvv(String cvv) {
        this.cvv = cvv;
    }
    public String getCreditname() {
        return creditname;
    }
    public void setCreditname(String creditname) {
        this.creditname = creditname;
    }
    
    @JsonIgnore
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CreditCard [credit_id=" + credit_id + ", cardno=" + cardno + ", cvv=" + cvv + ", creditname="
                + creditname + "]";
    }
    
    

}
```

```
**UserController.java**

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.Grocery.Grocery.model.User;

import com.Grocery.Grocery.repository.GroceryRepository;





@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    
    
    
    @Autowired
    private GroceryRepository groceryRepository;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers()
    {
        return groceryRepository.findAll();
    }
    
     
     @GetMapping("/{id}")
     public ResponseEntity getbyid(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
            return new ResponseEntity(groceryRepository.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        } 
}
```

```
**CreditCardController.java**
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.Grocery.Grocery.model.CreditCard;

import com.Grocery.Grocery.repository.CreditCardRepository;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/creditcard")
public class CreditCardController {

    @Autowired
    private CreditCardRepository creditcardRepository;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<CreditCard> getAllCreditCard(){
        return creditcardRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    @ResponseBody
     public CreditCard createEmployee(@RequestBody CreditCard credit) {
         return creditcardRepository.save(credit);
     }

}
```

```
**GroceryRepository.java(UserRepository.java)**

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.Grocery.Grocery.model.User;


@Repository

public interface GroceryRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    

    List<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

```
**CreditCardRepository.java**

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.Grocery.Grocery.model.CreditCard;

@Repository
public interface CreditCardRepository extends JpaRepository<CreditCard, Integer>{

    
}
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaf       awe fffffffffffff                     ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeggg gggg gggggggggggggggggg kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: I think that your sql schema does not correspond to the annotations on `private User user`. Check the properties of the column `uid` of the table `credit_card`: it is probably not nullable.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If am giving "uid" as null in "credit_card" table its not storing the value of "uid" in the table, it showing as null. I don't need a null value in the table, it should show me the value which I have given via post method.